# I want to know if there is a ANDROID API which allow caller to listen a different tone while before another person picks up phone

Tags: android, api, ringtone, telephonymanager

I want to know if there is a ANDROID API which allow caller to listen a different tone while before another person picks up phone? An ANdroid API or a code to replace tone by another one?

Thanks.

Comment: why is it not a real question?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "you cannot do that".  The tone is generated by the telephone company, not by the receiving handset.  Some mobile operators (in some countries) sell this service as an add on to your subscription: when somebody calls your number, they hear your pre-selected tone.  Because this tone is controlled by an entity before the call reaches the handset, it is not possible to change this tone from the handset, android or otherwise.